# Is there a way I can get links from pages other than the DOM in a firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to get links from other pages but since they aren't loaded I can't do something like this.

```js
var urlsFound = [];
var url = "https://www.youtube.com";

for(var i = url.links.length; i --> 0;)
{
    urls.push(url.links[i].href);
}

urlsFound.forEach((item, index) =>
{
    console.log(`${index} : ${item}`);
});
```

Now of course the code above won't work but it's there just to better illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish. How can I get links from other pages without loading them into the DOM while having it work in a firefox extension? I'm willing to use any technology provided it can work within a firefox extension.

Comment: can you load them into "a dom" instead "the dom"? Otherwise you can usually scrape links (not deep arbitrary html code) with RegExp.

Comment: Use `fetch(url)` to get the contents of the remote page.

Comment: Cheerio.js is a good HTML scraper. You just need to make a request, then use cheerio to get the links from the HTML string. https://cheerio.js.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a http request using something like fetch or axios and then parse the html and get the links, using cheerio. Here's an example.

You can see how to use `axios` and `cheerio` here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

https://cheerio.js.org/

```js
const axios = require("axios").default; // can use fetch etc.
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

function getLinks(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.get(url).then(res => res.data).then(HTML => {
      const $ = cheerio.load(HTML);
      const links = $("a").toArray();
      resolve(links);
    }).catch(err => reject(err));
  });
}
```

Comment: Bit late to get back but thank you very much. This was very helpful and has put me on the right track.